# How to compare values of two dictionaries that have different keys in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the dictionary of football match results that looks like:

```
results = {
    "31 August 2019": [
        [
            {"Lazio": 2}, 
            {"Roma": 1}
        ]
    ], 
    "1 September 2019": [
        [
            {"AC Milan": 0}, 
            {"Napoli": 3}
        ],
        [
            {"Udinese": 1}, 
            {"Fiorentina": 1}
        ]
    ]
}
```

[{"Lazio": 2},{"Roma": 1}] means Lazio VS Roma, score:2-1

What I need is to get the winner for each match by comparing two dictionaries for a match. I have try this:

```
for date, matches in results.items():
    for match in matches:
        if match[0].value() > match[1].value(): #I'm Stuck on this
            print(date)
            print("the winner is :", match[0].key())
        elif match[0].value() < match[1].value(): #I'm Stuck on this
            print(date)
            print("the winner is :", match[1].key())
        else:
            print(date)
            print("the match between ",match[0].key()," VS ",match[1].key()," was even")
```

Of course that code didn't work but I hope you could understand what I mean.
if you have a better format to save the results, please tell me.
Thanks a lot

Comment: Where do you get `results` dictionary? It's structure is bad and makes it harder to operate on your data.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @Asocia I just made it by myself with my knowledge. if you have any suggestion for better structure, please tell me

Comment: @harjed Check [alaniwi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62540165/9608759)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dictionary `{'AC Milan': 0}` is not a convenient format compared to simply using something like a 2-tuple `('AC Milan', 0)`.

Here is one suggestion for how to extract the data:

```
results = {'1 September 2019': [[{'AC Milan': 0}, {'Napoli': 3}],
                                [{'Udinese': 1}, {'Fiorentina': 1}]],
           '31 August 2019': [[{'Lazio': 2}, {'Roma': 1}]]}

for date, matches in results.items():

    for match in matches:
        t1, t2 = [next(iter(d.items())) for d in match]
        team1, score1 = t1
        team2, score2 = t2

        if score1 > score2:
            print(team1)
        elif score2 > score1:
            print(team2)
        else:
            print("the match between {} VS {} was even"
                  .format(team1, team2))
```

Gives:

```
Napoli
the match between Udinese VS Fiorentina was even
Lazio
```

Changing them to 2-tuples, this becomes a lot easier.  For example:

```
results = {'1 September 2019': [[('AC Milan', 0), ('Napoli', 3)],
                                [('Udinese', 1), ('Fiorentina', 1)]],
           '31 August 2019': [[('Lazio', 2), ('Roma', 1)]]}

for date, matches in results.items():

    for match in matches:
        t1, t2 = match
        team1, score1 = t1
        team2, score2 = t2

        # ... etc ...
```

(Or even just `for t1, t2 in matches:` in place of the `for match ...` and following statement.)

Comment: Thanks a lot, i just realize that there is tuple in python.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue in your code is that dictionaries don't have a `.value()` method, even if they have only one key, value pair.   For the provided data structure, you need to instead do something like this, getting the value out of each single element dictionary by `list(dict.values())[0]` (note that this is an alternative (and a slower one) to the `next(iter(d.items()))` seen in other answers):

```
for date,matches in results.items():
    for match in matches:
        if list(match[0].values())[0] > list(match[1].values())[0]:
            print(date)
            print("the winner is :", list(match[0].keys())[0])
        elif list(match[0].values())[0] < list(match[1].values())[0]:
            print(date)
            print("the winner is :", list(match[1].keys())[0])
        else:
            print(date)
            print("the match between ",list(match[0].keys())[0],
            " VS ",list(match[1].keys())[0]," was even")
```

But I agree with other posters that the data structure could be improved to make this feel less poor.

My suggestion for a conversion would be to have a list of 2-element dictionaries for each date (with still key = team and value = score).  Then you could do something like this, which feels much simpler:

```
results = {"31 August 2019": [{"Lazio": 2, "Roma": 1}], "1 September 2019" : [{"AC Milan":0,"Napoli":3},{"Udinese":1,"Fiorentina":1}]}

for date,matches in results.items():
    for match in matches:
        print(date)
        maxi = max(match, key=match.get)
        mini = min(match, key=match.get)
        if match[maxi] == match[mini]:
            print("the match between ",maxi," VS ",mini," was even") 
        else:
            print('the winner is: ', maxi)
```

Answer (score 0):

`match[0]` and `match[1]` are both dictionaries here, which doesn't have a value method. A dictionary can multiple key and values, so it wouldn't make any sense to have a "value" method for retrieving one value.

Instead, it has `.values()` method that returns an iterable that can be used to iterate through all the values. If you are sure that the dictionaries are always going to contain one and only one value, you can retrieve it with `next(iter(match[0].values()))`. This will retrieve only one value if there multiple values and will throw an exception if the dict is empty. So, your comparison looks like `if next(iter(match[0].values())) > next(iter(match[1].values())):`

But, If you have control over the structure of `results`, I would avoid this. Using a dict to store one key value pair is not appropriate. Use a tuple instead.